# Get SVG content receives from API and add as ImageOverlay in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, svg, jaggery-js

**1. I manually copied the svg content to a svgMap.svg and accessed as follow**

```
var imageUrl = 'assets/img/svgMap.svg';
L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds, {opacity: 0.7}).addTo(map);
```

and this its working as expected.

Since there I coudnt find a way to save those svg content in the server side. I used jaggery.js, so that I could access the svg image in the same way I accessed it before.

**2. jaggery.js File.write() encodes special characters ( eg: apostrophe )**

This didn't work, though, because jaggery.js encodes special characters. I wanted to write a svg content on a file (svgContent.svg) when using the following

```
var file = new File("../filePath" + "fileName.svg");
file.open("w");
file.write(svgMap);
file.close();
```

This is because jjaggery.js encodes with latin1 and svg content is in UTF-8.

Are there any alternative way to get this SVG content to the image overlay?

Comment: I used a call to a java class method from my jaggery js and made it work. Thanks a lot for your concerns.

Comment: If your solution might be of any interest to other users, please try to phrase an answer sharing your insights with the rest of the community. If it is just a trivial solution, you might want to consider deleting your question altogether.

Comment: I was using my jaggary application on top of a carbon product in wso2. I called the java function using the mentioned ways in http://madhukaudantha.blogspot.com/2014/02/using-java-method-from-jaggery-file.html